# Pseudosphere using Lens glare?

Tags: geometry, physics, curvature

Not sure if this question fits here. Will try anyway.

I was recently going through Tensor calculus and GTR and realized the concept of Curvature and Negative curvature and then the new Westworld episode comes out and I notice this lens glare on the screen.

[image: Westworld Lens Glare]

Notice how the ***lens glare*** appears to be a psuedosphere here. As the camera pans and the sun moves, while it does appear to rotate, I just believe that is compression happening on a 2D plane that looks like rotation in a 3D space.

So the question I want to ask is, is this normal? Can lens with curvature produce negative curved images of positive curved objects? If yes, how? Or am I missing something very basic here?
Can anyone guide me towards the mathematics of this?

Comment: What is a psuedosphere?